# get access to style property of a div that is an array item

Tags: javascript, html

so i was learning some javascript animations the red and white circles https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xW-58hkF6pA , and it worked but the code was very long is it possible to make an array of divs and apply changes on them in a loop

```
var circles=[
        document.querySelector("#circle1"),
        document.querySelector("#circle2"),
        document.querySelector("#circle3"),
        document.querySelector("#circle4"),
        document.querySelector("#circle5"),
        document.querySelector("#circle6"),
    ];

function zoom(){

        for(var i=1;i<=6;i++){
        circles[i].style.width=circles[i].clientHeight+4+"px";
        circles[i].style.height=circles[i].clientHeight+4+"px";
        }  
  /*here conditions and stuffs*/
     requestAnimationFrame(zoom)
    }
    zoom()
```

this is the result on console :

```
  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

 console.log(circles[0]);/*result <div class="circle" id="circle1" > 
 </div> and selects the div in the page /*
```

even this doesn t work

```
    function zoom(){

        for(var i=1;i<=6;i++){
            clientH=circles[0].clientHeight+4+"px;"

     circles[i].setAttribute("style","width="+clientH+"height="+clientH);
        }  
     /*here conditions and stuffs*/
     requestAnimationFrame(zoom)
    }
    zoom()
```

ps: if i use querySelecor('#circle'+i).style.width=etc it work fine so loops are ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your loop conditions. You're out of bounds in the last iteration. Here's a safer approach where you begin at zero (the first element in the array) and end at the last element.

```
for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) { ... }
```

```js
var circles = [
  document.querySelector("#circle1"),
  document.querySelector("#circle2"),
  document.querySelector("#circle3"),
  document.querySelector("#circle4"),
  document.querySelector("#circle5"),
  document.querySelector("#circle6"),
];

for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
  circles[i].style.width = circles[i].clientHeight + 4 + "px";
  circles[i].style.height = circles[i].clientHeight + 4 + "px";
}
```

```css
div[id] {
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="circle1"></div>
<div id="circle2"></div>
<div id="circle3"></div>
<div id="circle4"></div>
<div id="circle5"></div>
<div id="circle6"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eycsdfp9/

Comment: @MedMouradElHayani I've included a working example for you as well as a link to the fiddle.

Comment: ohh it actuall worked  i kept 1->6 when i was testing  querySelecor('#circle'+i) feels dump thank u sorry can t upvote cause i m new have a nice day

Comment: @MedMouradElHayani Understood, but I'd appreciate it if you can mark my answer as the chosen one.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest to use this method

add `data-attribute` like `data-name` in this example and apply CSS on the basis of your `data-attribute` so that you don't have to get CSS conflict in another document model.

```js
var circles = [
  document.querySelector("#circle1"),
  document.querySelector("#circle2"),
  document.querySelector("#circle3"),
  document.querySelector("#circle4"),
  document.querySelector("#circle5"),
  document.querySelector("#circle6"),
];

for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
  circles[i].style.width = circles[i].clientHeight + 4 + "px";
  circles[i].style.height = circles[i].clientHeight + 4 + "px";
}
```

```css
div[data-name="circle"] {
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
div[data-name="user"]{
background-color:yellow;
color:black;
font-size:18px;
}
```

```html
<div data-name="user" id="user1">Sushil</div>
<div data-name="circle" id="circle1">one</div>
<div data-name="circle" id="circle2">two</div>
<div data-name="circle" id="circle3">three</div>
<div data-name="circle" id="circle4">four</div>
<div data-name="circle" id="circle5">five</div>
<div data-name="circle" id="circle6">six</div>
```